How to prevent variables of same type replicate values?
I have this code, that's replicating without any reason, my issue is when I try to change values in 'NewRow' its automatically gets copied to 'CurRow', I want to create copies of 'CurRow' and each row has a different value in 'Gmtrs.weight'.
var CurRow = db.Fold_Trans.AsNoTracking().First(x => x.ID == Id);

List<Fold_Trans> LsFoldTrans = [CurRow];

var OrgGmtrs = decimal.Parse(TxtOrgGMtrs.EditValue);
var TpMtrs = decimal.Parse(TxtTPGMtrs.EditValue);
var BalMtrs = decimal.Parse(OrgGmtrs - TpMtrs);

var OrgWt = decimal.Parse(TxtOrgWt.EditValue);
var OrgAvgWt = decimal.Parse(TxtOrgAvgWt.EditValue);
var TpWt = decimal.Parse(OrgAvgWt * TpMtrs);
var BalWt = decimal.Parse(OrgWt - TpWt);

var NewRow = CurRow;

CurRow.ID = Id;
CurRow.Gmtrs = BalMtrs;
CurRow.Weight = BalWt;

int ExCn = 1;

string NewPieceNo = CurRow.Piece + @$"-TP{ExCn}";
string NewMainPieceNo = CurRow.MainPiece + @$"-TP{ExCn}";

NewRow.Piece = NewPieceNo;
NewRow.MainPiece = NewMainPieceNo;
NewRow.Gmtrs = TpMtrs;
NewRow.Weight = TpWt;

NewRow.ID = 0;
LsFoldTrans.Add(NewRow);

db.Fold_Trans.AddUpdateOrDeleteCommRange(LsFoldTrans, x => x.ID == Id);
db.SaveChanges();

How can this behavior be prevented and what do I need to do so this doesn't happen again in whole project?
I'm using .NET 8 with EF Core and SQL Server.

You set "var NewRow = CurRow;"  These are reference variables, so they just point to the same value in memory.  So you need to create a new instance variable of NewRow and copy the value across.  As it is not possible to see from your code what type NewRow is then it is difficult to provide more details.  But this should help you in the right direction.   You also need to read up on the difference between a reference and value variable in C# to understand why this has happened and how to avoid it again.

I apparently solved by converting the CurrRow to a json and converting back to Fold_Trans and store in NewRow did the trick... it does the trick but should read how to do this properly... but this does the trick for the task.

This code shows a very deep misunderstanding of what EF is and even how reference types are. Those aren't rows, they're objects. EF isn't a database driver or connection, that's what ADO.NET is. Like all ORMs, deals with entities, not tables and rows, and tries to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. Worse, NewRow isn't a copy of CurRow, it is the exact same object. When you call Add you're actually trying to attach the same object back to a DbContext that ....... doesn't allow tracking. At best you'll get an error, worst case duplicates

@Ahmed I apparently solved by converting ... to a json not at all, that just silenced the error and added even more. And I suspect there are even more bugs in AddUpdateOrDeleteCommRange, a method that neither exists nor is needed in EF. SaveChanges automatically detects all changes to the objects it tracks and saves them in a single database transaction. Using AsNoTracking() broke the persistence mechanism. Whatever AddUpdateOrDeleteCommRange just tries to recover the functionality lost

The issue you're experiencing is because NewRow is referencing the same object as CurRow. In C#, when you assign one object to another, they both reference the same memory location. To create a true copy of the object, you need to clone it. Since Fold_Trans is an Entity Framework entity, you can manually create a deep copy of the object.
Here's an example of how you can create a copy of CurRow:

Create a method to clone your Fold_Trans object.
Use this method to create a new instance for NewRow.

Below is the modified code:
var CurRow = db.Fold_Trans.AsNoTracking().First(x => x.ID == Id);

List<Fold_Trans> LsFoldTrans = new List<Fold_Trans> { CurRow };

var OrgGmtrs = decimal.Parse(TxtOrgGMtrs.EditValue.ToString());
var TpMtrs = decimal.Parse(TxtTPGMtrs.EditValue.ToString());
var BalMtrs = OrgGmtrs - TpMtrs;

var OrgWt = decimal.Parse(TxtOrgWt.EditValue.ToString());
var OrgAvgWt = decimal.Parse(TxtOrgAvgWt.EditValue.ToString());
var TpWt = OrgAvgWt * TpMtrs;
var BalWt = OrgWt - TpWt;

// Clone the CurRow object to create a new instance for NewRow
var NewRow = CloneFoldTrans(CurRow);

CurRow.Gmtrs = BalMtrs;
CurRow.Weight = BalWt;

int ExCn = 1;

string NewPieceNo = CurRow.Piece + @$"-TP{ExCn}";
string NewMainPieceNo = CurRow.MainPiece + @$"-TP{ExCn}";

NewRow.Piece = NewPieceNo;
NewRow.MainPiece = NewMainPieceNo;
NewRow.Gmtrs = TpMtrs;
NewRow.Weight = TpWt;
NewRow.ID = 0;

LsFoldTrans.Add(NewRow);

db.Fold_Trans.AddUpdateOrDeleteCommRange(LsFoldTrans, x => x.ID == Id);
db.SaveChanges();

Fold_Trans CloneFoldTrans(Fold_Trans source)
{
    return new Fold_Trans
    {
        // Copy all the properties from source to new instance
        Piece = source.Piece,
        MainPiece = source.MainPiece,
        Gmtrs = source.Gmtrs,
        Weight = source.Weight,
        // Copy other properties as needed
        // Ensure not to copy the ID if you want a new row in the database
        // Exclude any properties that should not be copied
        // You may also want to include any navigation properties if needed
    };
}

In this code:

CloneFoldTrans method creates a new instance of Fold_Trans and copies
the values from the source object.
NewRow is created by cloning CurRow to ensure they do not reference
the same object.
CurRow and NewRow can then be independently modified without
affecting each other.


You should probably mention the difference between reference types, i.e. classes, and value types, i.e. structs. Records might also be useful to mention, since they make it much easier to create a modified copy of an object.
